# Toggle geojson labels using control with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am attempting to create my first leaflet map.  I am using OpenStreetMap tiles and adding geojson features as overlay layers. I have been following tutorials with much success, until I started trying to add labels.  I would simply like to add static labels to several features, and be able to toggle them on/off with the layer control.  I have been using [leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label).  Is this possible?

I have tried the following to give me labels with mixed results:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
          <!-- shows label only on mouseover -->
          //layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.name, { 'noHide': true});

          <!-- creates static labels, but remain when layers are turned off -->
          //var label = new L.Label();
          //label.setContent(feature.properties.name);
          //label.setLatLng(layer.getBounds().getCenter());
          //map.showLabel(label);
       }
   }
```

Here is my layer control:

```
var overlayMaps = {
    "Layer 1": L.geoJson(layer1geojson, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map),
    "Layer 2": L.geoJson(layer2geojson, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map),
    "Buildings": L.geoJson(buildingsGeojson, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map)
  };
var legend = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed:false});
legend.addTo(map);
```

**UPDATE**

I used the following technique proposed by ghybs to add labels to geojson features and have the ability to turn them off with the layer control.

```
var buildingGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
L.geoJson(buildings, {
    style: buildingStyle,
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var label = new L.Label();
        label.setContent(feature.properties.name);
        label.setLatLng(layer.getBounds().getCenter());
        buildingGroup.addLayer(layer);
        buildingGroup.addLayer(label);
    }
});
// Repeat for any additional layers with labels

// Add Group to overlays
var overlays = {
    "Layer1": layer1Group,
    "Layer2": layer2Group,
    "Buildings": buildingGroup
};

// Add layer control to map
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays, {collapsed:false}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: not sure on the toggle  on/off but on label onhover is available http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/64/

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks, I tried that first (see my OnEachFeature function), but I would like static labels (i.e. always visible, and fixed).  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CrqkR/6/) is what my labels look like now, but I'd like to hide them when their associated layer is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply need to create a "parent" [Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) that contains your GeoJSON feature layer(s) and their associated label(s).

Labels can be added to a group instead of directly to the map, so that they are removed / added to the map together with their Group.

```js
polygon.bindLabel('MultiPolygon dynamic label');

var label = new L.Label();
label.setContent("MultiPolygon static label");
label.setLatLng(polygon.getBounds().getCenter());
//map.showLabel(label);

// Create a Layer Group that will contain your GeoJSON feature layers
// and the static labels.
var polygonGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

polygonGroup.addLayer(polygon);
polygonGroup.addLayer(label);

L.control.layers(null, {
  "polygon": polygonGroup
}).addTo(map);
```

Of course you could do all that directly in your `onEachFeature` function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CrqkR/156/

Comment: I think this is the functionality I have been looking for.  Could you possibly elaborate on how I would incorporate it into my onEachFeature function?

Comment: I got it!  I'll post an update.

Answer (score 1):

Just to share an alternative method to "toggle" static labels with the leaflet control.  By listening for map [control events](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-baselayerchange), labels can be turned on/off with the controls.  For example:

```
//Create 2 group layers - 1 for geometry, 1 for labels
var groupLayer = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var groupLabel = L.layerGroup();
L.geoJson(layer1GeoJson, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {  
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) { 
            var label = new L.Label();
            label.setContent(feature.properties.name);                
            label.setLatLng(layer.getBounds().getCenter());

            groupLayer.addLayer(layer);
            groupLabel.addLayer(label);
        }
    } 
});

// Overlays
var overlays = {
    "Layer 1": groupLayer,
    // Add other layers here
};

// Add layer control to map
L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);

// Event listener for layers added to map
map.on('overlayadd', function (layer) {
    if (layer.name == 'Layer 1') {
        map.addLayer(groupLabel);
    }
});

// Event listener for layers removed from map
map.on('overlayremove', function (layer) {
    if (layer.name == 'Layer 1') {
        map.removeLayer(groupLabel);
    }
});
```

For my application, I used this approach because it allows me to turn layers and/or labels on/off depending on zoom level.